# Enforce mutually exclusive ARIA label attributes via types and modify the Props makes it incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

## The Setup

When worrying about accessibility in a component, only one label should exist: there should be either label, aria-label, or aria-labelled-by. (Exceptions should be rare; if you desperately need it, then do some casting to "any".) I'm trying to enforce that with a bolt-on type to make it easy to fall into the pit of success:

```ts
export type LabelWithAria<LabelType = string> =
  | { label?: LabelType; ariaLabel?: never; ariaLabelledBy?: never }
  | { label?: never; ariaLabel?: string; ariaLabelledBy?: never }
  | { label?: never; ariaLabel?: never; ariaLabelledBy?: string };
```

And then I add it to a component's props like this:

```ts
export type DropdownProps<TValue = OptionValues> = LabelWithAria & {
  value?: DropdownOption<TValue> | DropdownOptions<TValue> | null;
  rawValue?: TValue;
   ...a dozen or so other properties...
}
```

This works well when I'm writing my React components with all properties inside the JSX, though the error message is a bit long-winded (this minimal repro is okay, but it's common to have a dozen-plus props, which makes this much more verbose, often checking for multiple overloads):

```html
<Dropdown label="foo" ariaLabel="foo, only moreso" />
```

```
Type '{ label: string; ariaLabel: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PropsWithChildren<DropdownProps<any>>'.
  Type '{ label: string; ariaLabel: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ label?: ReactChild | undefined; ariaLabel?: undefined; ariaLabelledBy?: undefined; }'.
    Types of property 'ariaLabel' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
```

## The Problem

The problem comes when a more complex component has its props passed as part of the props object (for wrapper components). This usage below *should* be legal ("value" is optional anyway).

```ts
export interface InputOrValueProps {
  value: string | number | null | undefined | string[] | number[];
  selectProps?: Omit<DropdownProps, 'value'>;
  ...and other properties...
}

public render() {
  return <Dropdown {...(this.props.selectProps)} rawValue={this.props.value ?? ''} />;
}
```

This gives an error about ariaLabel:

```
Type '{ rawValue: string | number | string[] | number[]; validationErrors?: ValidationError[] | undefined; label?: ReactChild | undefined; ariaLabel?: string | undefined; ... 32 more ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PropsWithChildren<DropdownProps<any>>'.
  Type '{ rawValue: string | number | string[] | number[]; validationErrors?: ValidationError[] | undefined; label?: ReactChild | undefined; ariaLabel?: string | undefined; ... 32 more ...; }' is not assignable to type '{ label?: ReactChild | undefined; ariaLabel?: undefined; ariaLabelledBy?: undefined; }'.
    Types of property 'ariaLabel' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Also, when I mix-and-match the spread operator and JSX attributes, I get compile errors:

```ts
const props: DropdownProps = {
  options: [...],
  ... and the rest of the props...
};
...and a bunch more logic...
<Dropdown label="I am sad" {...props} />
```

The complaint is the same "ariaLabel is wrong" error:

```
Type '{ label: string; shouldDisplayLabelInline: true; styleOverrides: { root: { gridTemplateColumns: string; }; }; validationErrors?: ValidationError[] | undefined; ariaLabel?: string | undefined; ... 32 more ...;} | { ...; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PropsWithChildren<DropdownProps<any>>'.
  Type '{ label: string; shouldDisplayLabelInline: true; styleOverrides: { root: { gridTemplateColumns: string; }; }; validationErrors?: ValidationError[] | undefined; ariaLabel?: string | undefined; ... 32 more ...;}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PropsWithChildren<DropdownMCProps<any>>'.
    Type '{ label: string; shouldDisplayLabelInline: true; styleOverrides: { root: { gridTemplateColumns: string; }; }; validationErrors?: ValidationError[] | undefined; ariaLabel?: string | undefined; ... 32 more ...;}' is not assignable to type '{ label?: ReactChild | undefined; ariaLabel?: undefined; ariaLabelledBy?: undefined; }'.
      Types of property 'ariaLabel' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
```

This can be worked around a bit if the props object is of type `Partial<DropdownProps>`, but again, it's programmer-unfriendly with an obscure error message if you didn't get it right the first time.

Some of the issues are when I'm messing with types a bit, so that a wrapper component takes an `Omit<DropdownProps, "only" | "optional" | "props" | "omitted">`.

## A non-workable workaround

Yeah, it all works fine if I do a bunch of casts, but I'm making these components for other people to consume. And since those error messages are pretty bad at pointing out the solution (add a pointless cast!). As much as it's nice to get the ARIA-labelling "right", I don't want to have that at the cost of making it harder to use these components.

```html
 <Dropdown {...(this.props.selectProps as DropdownProps)} rawValue={this.props.value ?? ''} />
```

## A non-workable solution

I suppose it *might* be possible to define the DropdownProps using a heavily-redundant definition, but it's a maintenance nightmare *and* it means I have to do this for the ~20 different components we use that have a label and ariaLabel (and I'm not sure it would solve the above issues of passing/mixing props):

```
export type DropdownProps = {
  label?: string;
  ...all the usual props...
} | {
  ariaLabel?: string;
  ...same props again...
} | {
  ariaLabelledBy?: string;
  ...yet a third copy of the same props...
}
```

## The Goal

Really, the goal is just to have an easy mix-in type for the ARIA attributes that I can tack onto a component to make it easy to use ARIA labels correctly (no more than one ARIA-type-label on a particular component) while not making it harder to use or modify the component.

## The Repro

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: I followed this trilogy of a post only to find no minimal repro! Where's my repro? :(

Comment: @caTS, I've put together a repro. I'm pleasantly surprised at how easy it was to include random NPM packages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 different issues, although the error message is the same:

1. Mix-and-match of spread object props  and inline prop
2. Incompatible type once modified with `Omit`

---

## 1. Mix-and-match

> when I mix-and-match the spread operator and JSX attributes, I get compile errors

The problem is that by adding an explicit `label` prop on the `<Dropdown>` component, the rest of the props should "never" contain an `ariaLabel` or `ariaLabelledBy` prop (as specified by the `LabelWithAria` type).

But the "rest" of these props is spread from an object which is a full `DropdownProps` type, so it may very well contain one of these properties.

---

## 2. Incompatible type once modified with `Omit`

> Some of the issues are when I'm messing with types a bit, so that a wrapper component takes an `Omit<DropdownProps, "only" | "optional" | "props" | "omitted">`

As you figured out, as soon as you fiddle with your type, the new type becomes somehow incompatible with the original type, even though it may still be valid (only omitted optional properties, etc.).

It looks like TS does not handle very well the rework of union types which are meant for mutually exclusive properties, like your `LabelWithAria`:

```
// Define mutually exclusive properties
type Xor = {
    a: number
    b?: never
} | {
    a?: never
    b: number
}

// @ts-expect-error
const a: Xor = { // Error: Types of property 'a' are incompatible. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}

// Let's fiddle a bit with the type
type Modified = Omit<Xor, "whatever"> // It should theoretically be the same thing...

// Should have failed!
const m: Modified = { // For some reason, TS no longer enforces the mutual exclusion
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}

declare const m2: Modified;

// Should have been okay!
const b: Xor = m2; // Error: Type 'Modified' is not assignable to type 'Xor'.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=78&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEBEFMDMEsDtKgLYFcAuqCGAbHBPUSADwGMdUBnWANyQAcAnAe3skfVkkoCh182oABrNGoALygA3j1BzQWAFyh4qZACN2s+eoD8yxHUY8AvqAA+07XKz6VkI9dDqDazcZM8eIUAAF0lAC0JGyk6MGMLMakzPCU6ArKImKSUqA+AKKRosoAKgLcoMzQoEys7PygAORYVQqMSAgxyPRYnOo4kAB0oPmCVaoa7HWwlCrMCViU1ADm8FgdSOjMoPz9qPAAJjAIkJtVXU5KoACMADROLqAATKZePgAykOhVY3Cbm50KzrAJAO6-AAWq0BSwKfAKoAAssxNrA4HsJKAAPLIX4AHmSZ1AACI-oC2g52DiAHzpMAASQSlEBzFQOE2IMgomesFIuAIziWoNAlCwyG5CBmXRF9zAAGVafTGQS6KBoFhYJ1NgBCHgxOIJZDKGFwhGM1Lk0AAMVEvOYAtADSmsWxuXF41AOFiM3YRHg0FEpEK6B5aEwuCIZAo1FiR2U50uylunh423IWAaoA18RQ1x1sPhXE2AG4xaBJXSGaBZUhNJB4EUANZYfBqlMJK7JJHIa45o1ZKJ5SFVXVZvYjMbwCYKaawOYLL7LVY95IHHhAA)

---

A possible solution (for both issues) could be to split the `DropdownProps` to keep the Xor part separate, and work only on the "normal" props.

Unfortunately it means that the consuming component must take care of these separate definitions, and re-merge them after.

It is also possible to provide a helper type:

```
// Helper type
type WithAriaLabel<Props> = LabelWithAria & Props;

type DropdownPropsNormal = {
  options?: {label: string; value: string}[];
}

type DropdownProps = WithAriaLabel<DropdownPropsNormal>

type MixedProps = {
    wrapped: DropdownPropsNormal; // label is always provided externally, so wrapped cannot contain any ariaLabel/ariaLabelledBy => DropdownPropsNormal only
}

const MixedRepro: React.FunctionComponent<MixedProps> = (props: MixedProps) => {
    return <Dropdown {...props.wrapped} label="foo"/> // Okay
}

const PartialPropsRepro: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
  const spread: WithAriaLabel<Omit<DropdownPropsNormal, "options">> = {
    label: "whatTheFoo"
  }

  return <Dropdown {...spread}/> // Okay
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-V4oWhUv3eYBhcJwJCVmB+VT-Di0AA0SggcGbrfbcDQKFUqgg8F5apQg2cqloYeCYyDwRTd7k2mN3f9vf+cHB66ohI8ny8AVtWYTIH6IrEBK0qyqC4JKuA4JIGqoigTWLI6vqhrllWGH+uab5Ag2jY2naDoal2DrGOKtHxgGe5tuEoZenIABEmAQBAbFjNoA4APIANYTgBxYXvyWwuKC-yUhBOBQWKUoynKCHKshaqAthBEWsR+jifAigGqgHYrLwJwbJwoj8SAvCUWSJo9r8-xbmxILyoobGaDq9aNoOsJwGxrx8CgMBSHwSCSlxbEpIBJFkfajoftRtHioZRAoGEiS8XAAnCbQAFAA)

Comment: Welp, that makes me sad. It sounds like the LabelWithAria works great for the simple case, and falls apart once it gets more complex.